# AngularJS: Manipulate DOM for the New View Once Promise Is Resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angular-promise

Before user goes to the next page in my *AngularJS* app, I make a custom call to retrieve some data. I achieve this successfully with *AngularJS promise*

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) { $routeProvider
   .when("/", {templateUrl: "partials/home.html", controller:  "PageCtrl", 
               resolve: {delay: myFunction} })
```

...

```
 var myFunction = function($q, $timeout){
      var defer = $q.defer();
      myCustomAjaxCall({  
        success: function() {   
            defer.resolve();
          },  
        error: function() {    
            defer.reject('Reject error');
          }
      });
      return defer.promise;
 };
```

Note `myCustomAjaxCall` function. I have to use it as is. It makes the call and runs callbacks on success. This in turn resolved my promise.

This `myCustomAjaxCall` function tries to manipulate DOM for the new view. However, the *promise* is resolved before the new view is rendered. It is *router's* `routeChangeSuccess` method when the view is already changed and ready for DOM manipulation. For my case, however, it is too late because DOM is trying to be manipulated before the new view is rendered.

Is there any solution you suggest to follow to manipulate new view during *promise resolve* execution?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute code in defer.resolve itself. Have you tried?

```
defer.resolve(function() {
    // your code
})
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to run myCustomAjaxCall inside resolve() function? What will change? But thanks for hint

Comment: No, I'm thinking that when it's resolved that addressing the view at that point might be a solution for you. I've never tried this approach myself.